# NullPointerException after finishing SFTP transfer

Tags: android, chilkat

I'm receiving a null pointer execption at the end of a SFTP session.
What am I missing ?

This the error :

```
09-05 16:38:05.844 9298-9307/? E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
09-05 16:38:05.844 9298-9307/? E/System: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.sftp.SftpFileOutputStream.finalize(SftpFileOutputStream.java:203)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:187)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

NO errors from the library during the SFTP session.

Basically I log in to the SFTP server calling these functions :

```
    boolean success = sftp.Connect(hostname,22);
..........
    CkSshKey key = new CkSshKey();
..........
    String privKey = key.loadText(keypath);
..........
    key.put_Password(password); 
...........
    success = key.FromOpenSshPrivateKey(privKey);
...........
    success = sftp.AuthenticatePk(mPrefs.getSftpSapUser(),key);
```

Then I send the file :

```
    Boolean success = sftp.InitializeSftp();
.............
    success = sftp.UploadFileByName(remoteFilePath,localFilePath);
.............
    sftp.SetPermissions(remoteFilePath, false, 511);
```

What am I missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not a crash in Chilkat.  Look closely at the exception information:

com.**enterprisedt**.net.j2ssh.sftp.SftpFileOutputStream

The crash is in another software vendor's class (EnterpriseDT).   Or more accurately:  It might be a crash caused by incorrect usage of that vendor's class.  It's not necessarily a defect in that vendor's software.   (I really don't know..)